# How to convert Apache cookies back to String?

Tags: java, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

Here is my code:

```
 List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
```

Obviously, I can loop the `cookies` list and generate their String representation.

However, I wonder if it can be done with the Apache HttpClient API directly.

So if `cookies`contain the following cookies: `[foo=123, bar=123]`, how can I generate the String below with HttpClient API:

```
"foo=123; bar=123"
```

The method should take care of domain, path, expiration etc

**HttpClient 4.1.1**

Comment: Does it have to be such an old version of HC?

Comment: @oleg For my current use case, I can't upgrade to HC 4.3+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HttpClient 4.1**

```
BasicClientCookie cookie1 = new BasicClientCookie("foo", "123");
cookie1.setVersion(0);
cookie1.setDomain("origin.com");
cookie1.setPath("/");
BasicClientCookie cookie2 = new BasicClientCookie("bar", "123");
cookie1.setVersion(0);
cookie1.setDomain("origin.com");
cookie1.setPath("/");

BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie1);
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie2);

NetscapeDraftSpec spec = new NetscapeDraftSpec();
List<Header> headers = spec.formatCookies(cookieStore.getCookies());
for (Header header: headers) {
    System.out.println(header);
}
```

**HttpClient 4.5**

```
BasicClientCookie cookie1 = new BasicClientCookie("foo", "123");
cookie1.setVersion(0);
cookie1.setDomain("origin.com");
cookie1.setPath("/");
BasicClientCookie cookie2 = new BasicClientCookie("bar", "123");
cookie1.setVersion(0);
cookie1.setDomain("origin.com");
cookie1.setPath("/");

BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie2);
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie1);

RFC6265StrictSpec spec = new RFC6265StrictSpec();
List<Header> headers = spec.formatCookies(cookieStore.getCookies());
for (Header header: headers) {
    System.out.println(header);
}
```

Comment: Just for my curiosity, may you add the code for HC 4.3+?

Comment: It is not going to be much different. However as of HC 4.5 I would recommend using a RFC 6265 compliant cookie spec instead of legacy ones